# Playwright: Storing an element selector in variable

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, playwright

This might be a trivial question/answer, however I would like to know if there is a way that I could store an element locator in a variable and then reuse it same as it while working with Selenium and Page Object Pattern.

In my previous work I used to write automation test in Visual Studio and I used Selenium Web-driver along with Page Object Pattern approach. During my work on the Page Objects and later component, I could declare all selectors by FindBy annotation and then reuse it for the purpose of future tests. I have just started my adventure with Playwright and I was wondering if I could achieve same approach. So far all examples in web showed that each time when you have an element selector you perform already an action on it.

Lets say that I have a Page Object Class called "Home Page". On this page there is a "Submit" button. I would like to get location of this button and store in a variable so I can reuse it in the future. How can I achieve similar out which I used with FindBy annotation?

So instead of having common approach such as ->  `await page.click('button');`
I would like to have something which will look like this -> `const submitButton= [location of button tag];`

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  
    const browser = await playwright["chromium"].launch({ headless: false});
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-chromium.png` });
    locator = '[name="q"]'
    await page.fill(locator,"hiiiii")
  
})();
```

what stops you from storing element locator in a variable ?

Comment: PDHide I think that because of me being new to Playwright and JS and the materials which I saw of not having such simple examples. Thanks for providing an answer, however just one more thing if I may. Should I declare variables which will be storing element locators as const or let? Thanks!

Comment: @Automation_Padawan constant makes more sence as the locator is not going to change during run time. But using let or const doesn't affect the run in any way

Comment: Locator do change properties based on events in UI.

Comment: @Vishal constant is about the variable not the locator ,we don't modify the variable value on the run

Comment: Locator is just an string value of the variable which can change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Element Handle](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle/)

In Playwright terminology , an UI web element is called element handle. ElementHandle represents an in-page DOM element. ElementHandles variable can be created with the page.$(selector) method.

```
   const { chromium } = require('playwright');  // Or 'firefox' or 'webkit'.

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  const hrefElement = await page.$('a');
  await hrefElement.click();
  // ...
})();
```

As 'Element handle' resolves in to an promise , it can be used in various ways with  assertions to get and verify values from UI.

```
const tweetHandle = await page.$('.tweet');
expect(await tweetHandle.$eval('.like', node => node.innerText)).toBe('100');
expect(await tweetHandle.$eval('.retweets', node => node.innerText)).toBe('10');
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle/